# why function call returns error?

Tags: f#

I am trying out the following code in F# interactive and getting 'error FS0001: the type 'int -> int' does not match the type 'int'. Here is the code I am trying

```
> let rec factorial n = function
    | 0 -> 1
    | n -> n * factorial (n - 1);;
```

This is off of 'F3 for scientist' book example.
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've defined it, `factorial` takes two arguments, but you're only passing it one. Consequently, the second branch of the function is trying to multiply an `int` with a partially applied function of type `int -> int`.

The first line should read

```
let rec factorial = function
```

(sans `n`).

Answer (score 4):

Just to add some details about the syntax - the `function` keyword creates a function that takes an argument (implicitly, without naming it) and then allows you to pattern match on that value.

There are quite a few equivalent ways of doing this - using `function` as ildjarn described:

```
let rec factorial = function
  | 0 -> 1
  | n -> n * factorial (n - 1)
```

You can also declare `factorial` as a function taking `n` and then use `match`:

```
let rec factorial n = 
  match n with
  | 0 -> 1
  | n -> n * factorial (n - 1)
```

And for completeness, you can also create a function using `fun` (which is a simpler version of `function` that does not give you the ability to write multiple cases of pattern matching):

```
let rec factorial = fun n ->
  match n with
  | 0 -> 1
  | n -> n * factorial (n - 1)
```

The first two options are both idiomatic F# code - the second one is slightly more complex (without any good reason), so I'd prefer one of the first two.